# Preventing error_log flooding

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-fcgid, suexec, logging

Is there a way to have httpd/php stop logging errors if they are repeating over and over again to prevent flooding?

Currently the /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log file is getting flooded and would like to prevent that.

Comment: Is fixing the error out of the question?

Comment: It's a shared hosting setup so we have a lot of clients and a lot of errors. Some are more serious then others and flood the log files and we can't fix every little problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To piggy back what Michael said, I'd setup individual logging for each vhost.

This is a simple configuration change and should save you lots of headaches down the road.. Simply add an ErrorLog entry in each   entry. This also helps limit confusion for development and troubleshooting.

Once the individual logging has been enabled, your next step should be to setup log rotation on each of those directories/logs using logrotate.

Lastly, you could also configure/implement user quotas for those vhosts/users/homedirs and prevent their logs from eating all of the system's available hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

Split your error logs per VirtualHost and make the clients deal with their own web site errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I would not recommend, as Ladadadada asked you, it is better to fix error logs then to stop loggin, but if you are sure you want to stop logging errors here is what you have to do:

```
ErrorLog off
```